# tikz - annotation text not aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this example, the annotation text under the arrows not aligned horizontally ('cur' is higher than 'index' and 'key').

```
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=C1 going right,>=latex,node distance=0pt]
\definecolor{col1}{RGB} {238,51,34}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB} {153,221,153}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB} {255,255,51}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,fill=yellow!5,rectangle, minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.5cm,outer sep=0}}
\tikzset{arr/.style={->,line width=0.2pt}}
\newcommand\ann[3][]{
    \draw[arr,#1,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5cm]#2.south) node[below] {#3} -- (#2.south);
}
\foreach \val/\col [count=\i] in {1/col1,2/col1,3/col1,6/col2,5/col2,2/col2,4/col3} {
  \node[box,fill=\col,on chain] (N\i) {\val};
}
\ann[black]{N3}{cur};
\ann[black]{N5}{index};
\ann[black]{N7}{key};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your code to make it compilable. Especially with Ti*k*Z: you want people to guess their way through all the errors until they figure out individually what's needed when you could just have told those you are asking for help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is clearly explained (and solved) in one of the tutorials of the TikZ-PGF documentation at p. 67:

> The problem of mismatching baselines is caused by the fact that ...
>   omissis (editors's note: the text in the nodes) ... all have different
>   heights and depth. If they all had the same, they would all be
>   positioned vertically in the same manner. So, all Ilka needs to do is
>   to use the text height and text depth options to explicitly specify a
>   height and depth for the nodes.

Hence adding text `height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex` is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[chains]% please always put a complete mwe!

\begin{document}

\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=C1 going right,>=latex,node distance=0pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]
\definecolor{col1}{RGB} {238,51,34}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB} {153,221,153}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB} {255,255,51}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,fill=yellow!5,rectangle, minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.5cm,outer sep=0}}
\tikzset{arr/.style={->,line width=0.2pt}}
\newcommand\ann[3][]{
    \draw[arr,#1,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5cm]#2.south) node[below] {#3} -- (#2.south);
}
\foreach \val/\col [count=\i] in {1/col1,2/col1,3/col1,6/col2,5/col2,2/col2,4/col3} {
    \node[box,fill=\col,on chain] (N\i) {\val};
}
\ann[black]{N3}{cur};
\ann[black]{N5}{index};
\ann[black]{N7}{key};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

They are aligned. They are placed `below`. Hence, their `north` anchors are used to place them. They don't look aligned because `curr` is much shorter than the others.

To avoid this, you might use `mid`, say, to align them and add a bit more space to compensate when placing them.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\ann[3][]{
  \draw[arr,#1,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5cm]#2.south) node [below=5pt, anchor=mid] {#3} -- (#2.south);
}
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    start chain=C1 going right,
    >=latex,
    node distance=0pt,
    box/.style={draw,fill=yellow!5,rectangle, minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.5cm,outer sep=0},
    arr/.style={->,line width=0.2pt}
  ]
  \definecolor{col1}{RGB} {238,51,34}
  \definecolor{col2}{RGB} {153,221,153}
  \definecolor{col3}{RGB} {255,255,51}
  \foreach \val/\col [count=\i] in {1/col1,2/col1,3/col1,6/col2,5/col2,2/col2,4/col3} {
    \node[box,fill=\col,on chain] (N\i) {\val};
  }
  \ann[black]{N3}{cur};
  \ann[black]{N5}{index};
  \ann[black]{N7}{key};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned labels]